# Is it possible to use GCM to send push notifications between different applications?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

so I'm new to GCM and our project involves 3 different apps for 3 different type of users, namely: Student, Parent and Faculty. So the use case is that the Faculty cancels the class for today, and will send push notifications to all Students enrolled in that class. Now I've been reading and watching videos about GCM, and as far as I know it needs to have a unique key for the application that will send and receive the notifications. In this case, the sender of the notification is the Faculty app, and the receiver is the Student app. Is this at all possible? Or do we have to unite these 3 apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't worry of about sending notification if have server(generally every app has for central data management). server will do it.
if you planing to create same app (same package id but different view for different user) then server will track their unique key to track user type.

if you creating app with different version(different package id)  then you have to register Dev console GCM for reqest token  N times (N = no of different app package ids).

Comment: But do not forget about user registration in GCM.